# While loops crashes, but recursive function throws maximum call stack exceeded error

Tags: javascript, recursion, while-loop

This is a simple question but I couldn't find anyone addressing it.

Using chrome, running a program over localhost.
If I have a while loop that never breaks the condition, it causes the page to freeze, no erros and I cant even close the tab on chrome.

If I have a recursive function, that calls itself infinitely. A maximum call stack error will be thrown.

Why is there no fail safe for while loops? How can I avoid the page freezing when a while loop runs indefinitely?
(other than properly writing a while loop)

Comment: We can't help if we can't see your code...we can't see your screen...please add your code using the [edit] link below your question.

Comment: *"How can I avoid it"* ... by writing code that won't go into infinite loop. We've all done it at one time or another...just have to live and learn. worst case use a temporary counter that can break out while you debug the loop. Using `debugger` or breakpoint can help also

Comment: `Why is there no fail safe for while loops?` Infinite recursion is always undesired, an infinite loop otoh is standard stuff used in pretty much any game / software out there. Still, one game engine I know counts iterations and breaks if 15,000 is reached. You have to add a special keyword to prevent that.

Comment: @JackBashford What's the point of adding code? The question is perfectly fine without it.

Comment: Obviously writing a proper while loop is the best. my issues came from a bug that surfaced from a unique condition not found during development. In that unique condition the while loop would run forever and cause the page to crash with no errors which made troubleshooting difficult. I was just wondering if there was anything to identify that a while loop was indefinitely running, similar to how a recursive function will throw a maximum call stack exceeded error that can give you a hint of where to look for the error

Answer (score 1):

What you call fail safe is a missing feature in all implementations except Safari, which has implemented the ES2016 JavaScript requirement of [tail call optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). In safari you won't notice any difference between these:

```
while (true) {
  // code
}

(function loop () {
   // code
   loop()
})();
```

No stack overflow and as expected the browser freezes forever. The reason for that is that unless you are using workers JS is single threaded and no other JS code in the turn queue gets executed. eg.

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("This will never happen!"); }, 0);
(function loop () {
   loop()
})();
```

You should not write while loops that does not terminate. If you have made a bug i suggest you make a breakpoint in the while in order to check why it does not terminate. Alternatively you could if you think there is something wrong do:

```
// TODO: remove debug limit
let limit = 100000; // limit
while (true)) {
    if(!limit--) {
        console.log('limit exceeded');
        break; // set breakpoint here in debugger
    }
}
```

Backside is that you need to remove this when issue is solved. My IDE complains about that TODO so it will never ever go in git. You can do the same with tail calls:

```
// TODO: remove debug limit
let limit = 100000; // limit
(function loop () {
      // code
      if(!limit--) {
          console.log('limit exceeded');
          return; // set breakpoint here in debugger
      }
      if (true) loop(); // might have another expression than true
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use Chrome and leave the DevTools open.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The reason for why there are no safeguards against infinite loops such that exceptions are thrown for infinite loops is performance. Observe the different between checking and not checking.

```js
(function(){"use strict";

var i=0, performance_now = performance.now.bind(performance);
var end = performance_now()+200;
while (performance_now() < end) i=i+1|0;

console.log('Ops/sec with checking: ' + Math.round(i / 200 * 1000));


var k = 0;
i = i<<7;
var startTime = performance_now();
while (k < i) void (k=k+1|0);
var endTime = performance_now();


console.log('Ops/sec -- unchecked:  ' + Math.round(i / (endTime - startTime) * 1000));

})();
```

The version without timer-related safeguards is 300x faster. Albeit this is a bit exaggerated because most of the computing time is spent inside the loop instead of at the periphery, this ought to drive home to point of performance.

As for bypassing the limits of the stack in recursive functions, please see my own [DeferStackJS](https://github.com/anonyco/DeferStackJS) library which employs stack trampolining.

Comment: I had dev tools open and the page would still lock up from a while look that didn't break. Maybe  I'm missing something from your answer I'll have too look at this again

Comment: @JordanKlaers Notice how I ran `obj = null` to cause the while-loop to throw an exception and exit. Does causing the while loop to throw an exception work for you?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is there no fail safe?

You are the fail-safe.

While it is true that it is impossible for a computer to detect and intercept every conceivable infinite loop or infinite recursion, there are many examples (probably most examples that you'd practically write) for which the computer could actually do this.

But, to what end?

Language specifications generally don't require this. Implementations generally don't attempt this. Because they do not need to.

You test your code, and you find out that it does not behave properly. So you fix it.

That's really all that needs to happen. There's no need for complex algorithms that do the job for you 25% of the time with great computational effort.

You just fix the code.

> other than properly writing a while loop

Yeah that's literally the solution.

Comment: Obviously writing a correct while loop is right,  the issue was that when there was a while loop that ran indefinitely no error would show in the dev tools console of chrome and dude to the page locking up, and due to the error surfacing in unique conditions not found during development, there were no clues to find the source of the issue easily. I was just wondering if there was anything similar to what arrises from a recursive functional called over and over. That could be used to help troubleshooting. Or at least not lock up the page with no errors

Answer (score -2):

### The Halting Problem

This comes to mind, as it might not actually be possible to determine whether or not a while loop will deterministically run forever.

> In computability theory, the halting problem is the problem of
>   determining, from a description of an arbitrary computer program and
>   an input, whether the program will finish running (i.e., halt) or
>   continue to run forever.
>
> Alan Turing proved in 1936 that a general algorithm to solve the
>   halting problem for all possible program-input pairs cannot exist.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

### Chrome Solution

You can click the three dots in the top right corner and select

> More Tools > Task Manager > Force close tab

Comment: technically, chrome doesn't need to know whether it halts or not, It can simply work out if its taking too long / ensure the UI shell doesn't get blocked.

Comment: @KeithNicholas the first part was more of an "in-general" answer, but ya they definitely could do that in chrome

Comment: Interesting article.  Thank you for the force clost tab you suggested. I'll try that out

Comment: @JordanKlaers glad to help, the only reason it stops with infinite recursion is that the "stack" grows indefinitely as each stack frame consumes more and more memory, until all available memory is depleted.